# fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found (C++ in VsCode)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have issue with OpenCV. This is my first time, when i use this. I did download the openCV with Homebrew (Macos 13.2 Ventura) and i make a simple cmake project with this cmakelist:

```
`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(PROJEKTTEST1)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

set(OpenCV_DIR /opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.7.0_1/..)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(PROJEKTTEST1 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(PROJEKTTEST1 ${OpenCV_LIBS})


set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)`
```

And when i run this project i got this error:

szaboattila@Szabo-MacBook-Air projekttest1 % cd "/Users/szaboattila/Desktop/Programozás/projekttest1/" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "/Users/szaboattila/Desktop/Pr
ogramozás/projekttest1/"main
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Can help me what should i do?
The opencv path is: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.7.0_1/**

I added the path in cmakelist and the jsone file and it doesnt work...

Comment: It seems pretty clear from the command that failed that VSCode is not using the CMakelist file that you wrote, or at least that it's ignoring the OpenCV part of it. Disclaimer, I'm no CMake export.

Comment: And how can i fix this?

Comment: What you need to do is forensic investigation. For example, change the cmakelist file so that it says `main2.cpp` instead of `main.cpp` then do your build again. Do you now see any error message about `main2.cpp` not found? If so then that proves that the cmakelist file is being used. On the other hand if you see the same error message as before then that proves the cmakelist file is not being used. And so on. This how you solve these kind of problems. Make theories and test them, until you have narrowed down the problem to something you can solve.

Comment: Did you install the cmake extension "CMake Tools" in VS Code?

Comment: Yes, i downloaded all cmake extensions what i need